# PHP & SoapClient: parameters missing from SOAP request

Tags: php, web-services, soap-client

I am trying to fix an issue where it seems that SoapClient is not inserting the parameters into the SOAP request.

The simple test fails to a web service running on the same server as the website, which is PHP 5.3.13 on Windows 8 Server and IIS 7.1.  This had been working as recently as two days ago, but is now failing.  I am not aware of any changes to the server installation other than updates.

```
    function simpleTest(){

    $client = new SoapClient("http://server-sql:78/PCIWCTest/Service1.svc?wsdl", array( "trace" => 1 ));

    $result = $client->__soapCall("GetData",
    array('GetData'=> array('parameters'=> 'Hello')),
    array('soapaction' => 'http://server-sql:78/PCIWCTest/GetData'));

    $requXML = $client->__getLastRequest();
    $respXML = $client->__getLastResponse();

    debug($requXML);
    debug($respXML);
}
```

The resulting request ($requXML) is:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:GetData/></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I am assuming that there should be the string 'Hello' between the

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:GetData/></SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

tags, right?

I have been working with many different methods during troubleshooting like soap __call with the same results.  Server has been restarted.  I've tried all I can think and find to try.

Has anybody seen this before or have an idea?

Comment: Calling the "GetData" method directly on the `client` object produces the same problematic result?  I assume you're using the `__` methods to debug here, right?

Comment: Yes and yes.  $client->(GetData, $params) produces the same result.  I have also tried setting types on my params per some advice, and enclosing the params in another array to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, I discovered that the parameter I was sending was not named exactly as the parameter in the Web Service code.  By changing the above:

```
array('GetData'=> array('parameters'=> 'Hello')),
```

to:

```
array('GetData'=> array('value'=> 'Hello')),
```

the call worked normally and the parameter was no longer blank!  I don;t know if this behavior is unique to this situation, but in my limited experience, I have not seen a situation where it mattered what the parameter was named on the other end.

At any rate, issue is solved.  Hope this helps someone!