# IIS with PHP: How to get the data from a SOAP envelope?

Tags: php, iis, soap

An external application is calling my PHP script and passing URL parameters and a SOAP envelope. I can access the URL parameters in the $_GET array. However I cannot access the SOAP envelope. I was expecting it in the $_POST array, but that is empty.

The IIS log clearly shows that the SOAP envelope is being received by IIS but somehow I cannot access it in PHP - or I am using the wrong methods/variables.
When I check the "failed requests log" in IIS, I see the SOAP data as "GENERAL_REQUEST_ENTITY".

However I am at a loss when trying to access said data from within my PHP script. Is this kind of content stored in a different variable (other than $_GET, $_POST or $_REQUEST)? Or is IIS not forwarding this to my script and if so, why not?

Edit: I am not tied to PHP if PHP is not capable of doing this, I am open to any language that gets the job done. However my knowledge of ASP.NET is more limited than that of PHP. Is there a better language for capturing the missing data from the request?
This problem is not going away and I need to find a solution. So far no matter how much I search via Google, I keep running into dead ends.

Edit #2: Here is a screenshot of the log file for clarification. It clearly shows the XML and so does Fiddler, which I have also just now tested:

[image]

How can I capture this XML with PHP (or ASP.NET for that matter)?

Best regards
Max

Comment: Is it in `$_SERVER` possibly?

Comment: I just checked. Unfortunately no, $_SERVER does not include the SOAP envelope.

Comment: Is [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14146996/php-soapclient-parameters-missing-from-soap-request) helpful to your problem ?

Comment: Unfortunately no, as this looks at a client application. The client then performs a SOAP-based request. However in my case a 3rd party app performs a SOAP request against my PHP script.

Comment: Is there any other programming language which I can use on IIS to capture the SOAP envelope? I am not tied to PHP but PHP is what I know best.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201822/read-soap-message-using-c-sharp) is a sample to read SOAP message by C# for your reference.

Comment: Unfortunately reading (as in "parsing") the XML is one steap ahead of where I'm at. At the moment I fail to capture the raw XML from the caller. Is there a way to capture this? As said, I can see the XML being provided to my IIS server (by means of the IIS logging) but I cannot access it in my PHP script.